# MMQGIS is not geocoding my CSV

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I have a CSV, encoded in utf-8, that I'm trying to geocode:
[image]

When I run the MMQGIS geocoder, it doesn't encode anything. It doesn't give me an error-- it just says "Geocoded 0 of 49".

How can I figure out what is causing this plugin to fail?

[image]

Comment: could you add an image of the full table, especially your geocoded fields (Site Adress, Site City and State)?

Comment: full table is pretty long, but since none of them are getting geocoded, hopefully this is good enough to help troubleshoot? https://i.imgur.com/Pm5q1VT.png

Comment: I also added a "Country" field, but still no luck.

Comment: What happens if you try the OpenStreetMap geocoder?

Comment: All of my addresses are in my state and OSM thinks they are in other countries.  Google returns 0 results.  There is no error.  I am extremely disappointed in this software.